# y from the same row as max x sqlite documentation

Tags: sqlite, documentation, greatest-n-per-group

while reading the sqlite [change log](http://www.sqlite.org/changes.html#version_3_7_11) I came across this statement

```
2012-03-20 (3.7.11)
...
Queries of the form: "SELECT max(x), y FROM table" returns the value of y on the same row that contains the maximum x value.
...
```

I found the [commits that implement](http://www.sqlite.org/src/timeline?r=output-minmax-row) this feature, in the hope of finding documentation but no luck.

I find myself using this feature all the time and wondering:

- Is there documentation of this feature?
- When can I rely on it applying?
- Are there gotchas in using it?
- Are there similar queries that it doesn't work for?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You have quoted the entire documentation of this feature.

This does not work if there are multiple occurrences of max()/min() (you cannot choose which is the controlling one), or if the max() is not actually computed because an outer query ignores it.

Comment: thanks for the confirmation. can you elaborate on "not actually computed because an outer query ignores it"

Comment: `SELECT y FROM (SELECT max(x), y FROM ...)`

Comment: so in that case y is not necessarily form the row with x = min(x)?